# No newline at end of file when entering diff command on vi

Tags: c, encryption

I'm so tired of debugging and changing my code but every time it gives me:

```
No newline at end of file
```

when I try:

```
diff main.c output.txt
```

My program encrypts/decrypts the input textfile and it gives a correct output when it converts but when I enter `diff main.c output.txt` then it would always point me to that error. What should I do to prevent that? Any help would be appreciated!

```
int encryptFile(FILE *input, FILE *output){
    char c;
    char p;
    int r = 0;
    char p1 = 0;
    char c1 = 0;
    int index = 0;
    char line[100];
   // while((p = fgetc(input)) != EOF){
      while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), input) != NULL){
        for(index = 0; line[index] != 0; index++){
        p = line[index];
        r = rand() % 97;

        if(p == 't'){
            p1 = 0;
        }
        else if(p == '\n'){
            p1 = 1;
        }
        else{
            p1 = p - 30;
        }

        c1 = p1 ^ r;
        if(c1 == 0){
            c = 't';
        }
        else if(c1 == 1){
            c = '\n';
        }
        else{
            c = c1 + 30;
        }
        //Write
        fputc(c, output);
    }
      }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: How can this be answered without seeing the routine used for decryption?

Comment: @Michi, the algorithm is correct. I've checked it with my professor

Comment: @alk, the question is updated

Comment: @KemalP. I deleted already my comment after I saw again your code

Comment: You expect the encrypted text to be terminated by a new-line?

Comment: "*What should I do to prevent that?*" why do you care at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a new line at the end of your `output` file:

```
int encryptFile(FILE *input, FILE *output)
{
    char c = 0;
    char p;
    int r = 0;
    char p1 = 0;
    char c1 = 0;
    int index = 0;
    char line[100];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input) != NULL) {
        for (index = 0; line[index] != 0; index++) {
            p = line[index];
            r = rand() % 97;
            //change all displayable characters [0...96]
            if (p == 't') {
                p1 = 0;
            } else if (p == '\n') {
                p1 = 1;
            } else {
                p1 = p - 30;
            }
            c1 = p1 ^ r;//bitwise xor
            if (c1 == 0) {
                c = 't';
            } else if (c1 == 1) {
                c = '\n';
            } else {
                c = c1 + 30;
            }
            //Write
            fputc(c, output);
        }
    }
    if (c != '\n') {
        fputc('\n', output);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Or use:

```
diff --ignore-all-space file1 file2
```

Comment: if(c!= '\n') should be after executing for-loop ? @AlterMann

Comment: @KemalP., yes, at the very end.

Comment: But it says `comparison between pointer and integer`? @AlterMann

Comment: It compiles without warnings for me, `c` is a `char` not a pointer, but edited, I post the entire code.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `c` to `0`, there is another edit.